# How to create animations for a game like Creative kill chamber?

Tags: animation, flash

Lately, I have been playing Creative kill chamber game (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SW6PyOy34fY). This game is a flash game where gameplay is "hardcoded". I mean, it is a game where player can access a set of otpions in each situation and an animation is played as the result. The tree of possible paths gameplay can follow is small and finite and more important, it is totally deterministic.

My main question is, how do this guys create this type of animations? Are all they created using the time line? Are they using some kind of logic in code? I'm not used to flash so, can't say if this kind of animations can be quickly done.

On the other hand, if this animations are 99% done using just the timeline what tool would you use in unity to achieve something like this? The Dopesheet doesn't seem versatile enough.

Cheers.

Comment: Please don't introduce or otherwise advertise a game in a supposed question. This is not a site for that purpose. Questions should not be scoped by time (when possible) and obviously not limited to replicating the exact thought process and practices of a specific developer. I vote to close this question.

Comment: I think providing a visual example through a video is the best way to make other users understand the kind of game I was talking about. I don't think this is not advertising and that wasn't my intention.

Comment: Seems like a point-and-click adventure game. I'd create animations for that much like the animations for almost anything else, so (to me at least) this question reduces to "how do I make animations", which is very broad. What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Well, it was my fault I wasn't clear enough. One of the things I would like to know is if animations (avatars navigation, for example when the player grabs a dead body from the floor, when player jumps, etc...) are all hardcoded using flash timeline (keyframes). Any example showing the tipical workflow used to create animations like this would be nice. I think I should say that I am interested in knowing how they created the little custscenes that are played after each player mouse interaction. I ask this because I'm looking a way to tweak animations like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is asks for a specific game's implementation details.